# Transform.RotateAround with Joystick Rotation

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, joystick

[image][image]
I want to rotate one object around another, so that it matches my current joystick rotation. I know `Transform.RotateAround` does this but I can't seem to find a way to match it with my joystick rotation.

This is my code so far:

```
void Update()
{     
    joystick = InputManager.ActiveDevice;

    moveInput= joystick.RightStickX;

    if(currentState != CoreplayerState.stager) {        
        RotateChar();
    }
}


public void RotateChar() {        
    transform.RotateAround(target.position, zAxis, moveInput * rotateSpeed);   
    transform.rotation = target.rotation;
}
```

Comment: I notice at the moment you're only using the x component of the joystick input - so pointing right will rotate counter-clockwise about the z axis, and pointing left will rotate clockwise. Is this what you want, or do you want to rotate to the angle the joystick is currently pointing? (eg. if I point my joystick diagonally up & right, should the object rotate to sit above & to the right of its pivot and stop at that point?)

Comment: Yeah I want it to work exactly as you pointed out, I just did not even try to map the vertical axis on the joystick because I never found a way to match my joystick position so I ended up only using the X axis of my joystick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can think of the x, y input on the joystick as just another vector in our game world. Transforming it through the pivot lets you match the plane of rotation to the orientation of the pivot.

How's this work for your use case?

```
public class JoystickMatch : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform pivot;
    public float radius = 1f;


   void Update() {
       var joystick = InputManager.ActiveDevice;
       var heading = new Vector2(joystick.RightStickX, joystick.RightStickY);

       if(heading != Vector2.zero) {
           transform.position = pivot.TransformPoint(heading.normalized * radius);
           transform.rotation = pivot.rotation;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted the previous answer accidentally, I guess I'm just very excited, give a second and I will post the screenshot with my issue.

Comment: So the white character is the pivot for the purple character and I want the purple character to be always away from the pivot around the distance of the image

Comment: How does that differ from the behaviour you get with this script or similar?

Comment: I am very ashamed for the lack of explanation, I just edited my opening post with the image of the current position of the purple character with the code you gave me (first image). I really thank you for all your patience and will to help me man.

Comment: Did you try increasing the value of the radius variable?

Comment: Yeah I event increased it to 100f. Could it be that the purple character is set as the children of the white character?

Comment: That alone shouldn't affect it, no. Can you edit your question to walk us through the steps needed to reproduce this problem in a new empty project?

Comment: I don't know what the heck I was moving but it is working perfectly fine with the same piece of codes you gave me. Is there a way that I can help you? Like a voting system for your help or something?

Comment: Click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted if it worked for you. :)

Comment: You can not imagine how long I have been struggling with that programming problem. I am so shocked to find out that you are a game designer. I have been trying to break into the industry in my country (Mexico) and I my dream is to someday work in big company in Canada as a game designer. You got a new fan here Douglas! :D